# Can a replacement set be uncountable?

Tags: set-theory, real-numbers

I apologize if I mess up my terminology here.

I was reading about solution sets recently and saw that for the formula "x + 1 = 1 + x" the solution set is equivalent to the real numbers.

That makes perfect sense. What doesn't is that I've been told that the set of all possible equations or formulas (both terms) is countable, but that the real numbers are not.

I understand why that is, given that well formed formulas are finite. However, it seems to me that if the solution set of "x + 1 = 1 + x" is the real numbers then the replacement set for that same formula must have the same number of members as the real numbers, which would make it uncountable, right?

That is, for every real number n there must be a replacement where a real number n is inserted into "x + 1 = 1 + x," for all the real numbers.

Is this a terminology issue? Would formulas lacking variables, such as those with actual numbers of the type appearing in the afformentioned replacement set, be named something else? Or for some reason is the replacement set still somehow countable, and if so why?

(Edited for clarity) Second ancillary question: if we took the union of multiple replacement sets for formulas that have the real numbers as their solution set, e.g. x + 2 = 2 + x; x + 3 = 3 + x... etc. could we say this set is larger than the set of real numbers? I thought this might be the case because the first replacement set has a member for every real number (provided this is the case, see above), then the second in the union *also* has a member for every real. Thus, you couldn't put the members of the union into a one to one correspondence with the real numbers because there would be multiple members of the combined replacement sets for each real number. Or does this not work?

Comment: Adding the cardinal number of two replacement sets where each of them denotes $\mathbb{R}$ does not increases its cardinal number...it still remains infinity

Comment: When you were told that the set of all possible equations or formulas is countable, how did they define "the set of all possible equations or formulas"? Because if you have an equation like $x = 0,$ and you suppose that $0$ could be replaced by any real number to produce a new equation, then you already have as many equations as real numbers and therefore an uncountable number of equations. But if we think about equations that can actually be written exactly in the real world, there are only finitely many in practice.

Comment: Is "replacement set" the same thing as "solution set"?

Comment: A replacement set is the opposite of the solution set. It's the formula with actual solution values plugged in the place of any variables such that it is a valid solution.

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad but we can have a set larger than the real numbers because the set of all subsets of the real numbers would be larger, correct? I wasn't sure if this could be another such case due to the one to many correspondence issue I have clarified in the second question section.

Comment: @TimBrown there is a set that is larger than real numbers or the real numbers set is a proper subset of that set...and that set is **the set of complex numbers**...you can't get a set larger than real numbers by combining two sets of real numbers

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad that makes sense. My thinking was that there would be a surjective function between the set of all replacement sets whose corresponding solution set is the real numbers, but not a injective (1 to 1) function because every element of the function's codomain is the image more than one element in its domain. That is, there would be multiple "equations" in the replacement set corresponding to each real number because many (but a finite number of) well formed formulas have the real numbers as their solution set. I am probably misunderstanding the functions though lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the fundamental issue you're having is that you're tacitly assuming that every real number can be represented by a formula.  That's not true.  There are only countably many formulas, so only countably many real numbers can be defined by a first-order formula.  So it's not correct that for every real number $r$ there's a replacement where the real number $r$ is inserted into $x+1=1+x$.  If there's no formula that allows you to define $r$, you can't sensibly talk about first-order formulas that include $r$ as a term.

Of course, that doesn't mean that there are only countably many real numbers -- as you know, the set of real numbers is uncountable.  But it does mean there are a whole bunch of real numbers that we can't specifically identify using a first-order formula, and that means we can't use them as the $r$ in $r+1=1+r$, not because the formula isn't true, but simply because there's no way to refer to that specific $r$.

As for your ancillary question, it's simply not true that the union of two sets having cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ (or any infinite cardinality) has larger cardinality than the individual components.  Just because the most obvious attempt at a bijection that you can think of doesn't work doesn't mean there are no bijections, and in fact, it's really not hard to show for any infinite cardinality $\kappa$ that the union of no more than $\kappa$ sets of cardinality $\kappa$ itself also has cardinality $\kappa$.

Comment: Thank you! I had been doing some digging on this and come to the same conclusion for those reasons, but I wasn't confident in my self-research attempts, not knowing that much about mathematical logic myself. It's helpful to hear it from someone who knows what they're talking about.

Answer (score -2):

I know that the set of all possible polyomial equations with rational(or some set with countably infinite) coefficents is countable. So that not all the equations are countable. In your case you basically say that 0=0 ant than you can change your equation like ex-ex = 0 and than this equation is not countable.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer appears to be simply incorrect. The union of two countable sets is a countable set. The union of countably many countable sets is a countable set.

Comment: Yes I already know that.